# Swift Realm change only one object value

Tags: swift, realm

```
class User: Object {
 @objc dynamic var id = ""
 @objc dynamic var dateFirstStart:TimeInterval = 0

//dates
 @objc dynamic var dateLastStart:TimeInterval = 0
 @objc dynamic var dateLastAppClose:TimeInterval = 0
 @objc dynamic var dateLastDataUpdateCheck:TimeInterval = 0
 @objc dynamic var dateLastFilesUpdateCheck:TimeInterval = 0
   override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
   }
}
```

Do I really have to create a function for each value to change? Like this:

```
    func updateUserDateFirstStart(date:Date){
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
            let user = getUser()
            user. dateLastStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

What I want is something like

```
let user = getUser()
user.dateLastStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
dataManager.updateUser(user)
```

And in my DataManager:

```
    func updateUser(user:User){
     do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
                 realm.add(user, update: true)
        }

     } catch let error as NSError {
        print("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }

   }
```

But if I do it as you can see in my wishtohave solution I always get an Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction error.

I tried to create a complete new Object and use the id from the object I want to change. This works but would need even more lines of code.

Comment: do you need update user object without use `realm.write` ??

Comment: No I want to temp. change the object an write it to DB  like I explained in "What I want is something like" Otherwise I would need to write one function per value, recreate and copy all values or at least put some together. I still hope that I missed something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use KVO  to update one value in realm object

how to call

```
    let user = getUser()
    self.update(ofType:user, value: Date().timeIntervalSince1970 as AnyObject, key: "dateLastStart")
```

Helper func

```
  func update(ofType:Object,value:AnyObject,key:String)->Bool{
            do {
                let realm = try Realm()
                try  realm.write {
                    ofType.setValue(value, forKeyPath: key)
                }

                return true
            }catch let error as NSError {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            return false
        }
```